# Running into transient NoMethodError errors with T.cast in production

Tags: ruby, sorbet

we’re running into transient `NoMethodError` errors in code paths using `T.cast` on our production services. Here are some notable facts

- Is happening in `sorbet-runtime` as of version `0.5.10012`
- It only affects 1 host at a time and often happens in short spurts (ex. errors for < 10m and goes away).
- On some of our production services, we’ll see errors daily. On others, it’ll be weekly
- We were not seeing this error until we upgraded sorbet-runtime versions from `0.5.6001` to `0.5.9976` (2 years of changes). We were pinned on the old version until we could migrate off the now deprecated `--dsl-plugins`
- Ruby version 2.7.4
- We have *disabled* runtime validation in production - `T::Configuration.default_checked_level = :never`

What it looks like is that `T::Utils.coerce(type)` returns an unexpected value (not a subclass of T::Types::Base) for a short period of time, which leads to errors here when checking `error_message_for_obj` here: [code](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/5f0656de31068a06537f21d6a875fcf1a53a5bed/gems/sorbet-runtime/lib/types/private/casts.rb#L8)

Recent stacktrace

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `valid?' for {:mode=>:compat}:Hash
  from sorbet-runtime (0.5.10012) lib/types/types/intersection.rb:33:in `block in valid?'
  from sorbet-runtime (0.5.10012) lib/types/types/intersection.rb:33:in `all?'
  from sorbet-runtime (0.5.10012) lib/types/types/intersection.rb:33:in `valid?'
  from sorbet-runtime (0.5.10012) lib/types/types/base.rb:133:in `error_message_for_obj'
  from sorbet-runtime (0.5.10012) lib/types/private/casts.rb:8:in `cast'
  from sorbet-runtime (0.5.10012) lib/types/_types.rb:133:in `cast'
  from < our code>
```

Where the line in our code looks like this

```
T.cast(self, T.all(T::Props::Serializable, Object)).as_json
```

I've not figured out a way to reproduce locally but I selectively enabled a debugging monkeypatch to `T.cast` to not raise some errors and log some more information.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module SorbetMonkeyPatches
  module TcastDebug
    module ClassMethods
      def cast(value, type, checked: true)
        super
      rescue NoMethodError => e
        Rails.logger.error(
          message: "[sorbet] - #{value.try(:class)} to #{type.try(:class)}",
          src_value: value.inspect,
          src_type: type.inspect,
          coerce_res: T::Utils.coerce(type).inspect,
        )
        value # ultimately don't want assertions from T.cast...this should return the same value unchanged
      end
    end
  end
end

if ENV["SORBET_DEBUG_UPGRADE"] == "true"
  ::T.singleton_class.prepend(SorbetMonkeyPatches::TcastDebug::ClassMethods)
end
```

When enabled, here are some sample log statements we see

```
[sorbet] - Class to Module {"src_value":"ProductsDomain::Api::LocaleCode","src_type":"T::Props::CustomType","coerce_res":"\"ssl_min_protocol_version\""}  
...
[sorbet] - Class to Module {"src_value":"ProductsDomain::Api::LocaleCode","src_type":"T::Props::CustomType","coerce_res":"[\"workflow_state\", \"active\"]"}
```

If working correctly, I would’ve expected `coerce_res` to return a subclass of `T::Types::Base`, not random strings

My uninformed opinion is that we’re somehow corrupting the cache for coerced types introduced by this PR - https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/4397 .

The questions I have

- Has this been seen before?
- Any advice for how to address or how to continue debugging?
- Ultimately we’d hope not to see errors from `T.cast` when runtime checks are disabled…[should we override the optional checked param](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/5f0656de31068a06537f21d6a875fcf1a53a5bed/gems/sorbet-runtime/lib/types/_types.rb#L130-L131) in the `T.cast` method definition?

Thanks for your help! Please let me know if you'd like any more debugging information

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how recently you upgraded to Ruby 2.7. When we did the Ruby 2.7 upgrade in our codebase, one of the failure modes we saw frequently looked like this:

`GC.compact` was being called by certain low-level framework code (If memory serves, I think `puma` calls `GC.compact` if available, regardless of whether your application calls it directly anywhere. There may be others. You could `grep` the contents of your `vendor/bundle` directory and see if any gems have calls to it, if your codebase doesn't.)

The problems is then that certain Ruby gems with C extensions, especially on versions of those gems that were released before Ruby 2.7 was released, would not properly declare that certain objects needed to be pinned in memory.

This means that the Ruby VM would compact its heap, it would move values around under the hood such that what used to be a `T::Types::Base` suddenly became some object formerly owned by a C extension.

In the end, we played whack-a-mole trying to find the offending gem for a while before deciding to monkey patch `GC.compact` to be a no-op very early on in the process load time, which fixed our issues. It's possible the same thing will fix yours.

Unfortunately, I can't see any codepath through sorbet-runtime which would cause the code at `lib/types/types/intersection.rb:33` to call `.valid?` on a `Hash` object, so I would be surprised if this were a Sorbet bug, but if you do manage to reproduce it, please file an issue against the Sorbet repo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the advice! We'll try a monkeypatch and will report back. We are using puma that calls `GC.compact` via the nakayoshi fork. We upgraded to ruby 2.7 in september 2021 and only starting seeing this problem recently so I'm currently thinking the issue results from some interplay between 1) `GC.compact` in ruby 2.7 2) some C extension not marking objects correctly and 3) the new usage of `ObjectSpace::WeakMap` in sorbet. Sound reasonable?  Also came across [this gitlab discussion that seems related on a PR](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/56079)

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware that sorbet-runtime was using WeakMap. If you suspect that WeakMap might be the problem, let me know and I’m happy to cut a temporary release that reverts the WeakMap changes.

Comment: Hmm we're still seeing the same issue despite disabling GC.compact. One service we noticed the issue on doesn't even appear to call it. We're still investigate but don't really have any solid leads. If you have the time, we'd appreciate being able to test a version without ObjectSpace::WeakMap. I'm also on the sorbet slack workspace if it's easier to coordinate there

Comment: for reference we're using sorbet-static-and-runtime at v0.5.10012...but we can upgrade to latest if that's convenient